# How to trigger Components#includeCompositeComponent() call?

Tags: jsf, composite-component, omnifaces

we are working on a JSF 2.1 / Facelet web application.

We have a complex composite component, acting as a switch/case, to include an other composite based on rendered attribute condition.

```
<h:body>
    <composite:interface>
        <composite:attribute name="form" type="com.my.Form" required="true" />
    </composite:interface>

    <composite:implementation>

        <my:form1 rendered="#{cc.attrs.form.type eq 'form1'}"/>
        <my:form2 rendered="#{cc.attrs.form.type eq 'form2'}"/>
        <my:form3 rendered="#{cc.attrs.form.type eq 'form3'}"/>
        <my:form4 rendered="#{cc.attrs.form.type eq 'form4'}"/>
        <my:form5 rendered="#{cc.attrs.form.type eq 'form5'}"/>
        ...
        <my:form10 rendered="#{cc.attrs.form.type eq 'form10'}"/>
        <my:form11 rendered="#{cc.attrs.form.type eq 'form11'}"/>
    </composite:implementation>
</h:body>
```

Each potentiel composite form is relatively complex.
The problem, as you may guess, is that the rendering performance are very poor.

I tried to use the omnifaces Components#includeCompositeComponent(), with no success.
Actually, I cannot figure out when/where/how trigger this.
I have tried with postAddToView event listener, interface's component type encodeBegin method, ... But none of them works.

Could anyone give me a starting point on the right way to proceed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to trigger it during the view build time. The `postAddToView` event listener approach must work. Perhaps you did it the wrong way. Here's a kickoff example:

```
<h:panelGroup>
    <f:event type="postAddToView" listener="#{bean.build}" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

With this, assuming that you have a `form.getType()` of `form1` and thus want to include `<my:form1 id="form1">` from `xmlns:my="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/somelibrary"`:

```
public void build(ComponentSystemEvent event) {
    if (Faces.isPostback() && Faces.isRenderResponse()) {
        return;
    }

    UIComponent parent = event.getComponent();
    String libraryName = "somelibrary";
    String resourceName = form.getType() + ".xhtml";
    String id = form.getType();
    UIComponent composite = Components.includeCompositeComponent(parent, libraryName, resourceName, id);
    // ... You can set its attributes here, if necessary.
}
```

Comment: Than you for answer! If I add the f:event in my composite (see initial question), how can I get _form_ attribute's value in the listener method? Actually, I need the value to determine what composite I will add dynamically, but 'e.getComponent().getAttributes().get("form")' returns null.

Comment: Inside the composite? I understood that you wanted to replace the wrapping composite because of it being expensive?

Comment: Looking at the snippet, the composite makes reference to several composites (only one rendered, all the others are not). This is the part I'd like to remove and add the single rendered composite <my:formX />.

Comment: I've clarified the answer. The `<f:event>` isn't supposed to be inside the composite anyway, it should replace the in the question shown "switch" composite altogether (as I initially understood; otherwise the performance concern makes little sense). So instead of `<h:panelGroup><my:switchFormComposite/></h:panelGroup>` you must use the above answered approach (where `<h:panelGroup>` is just an arbitrary parent, it can be any UI component you want).

Comment: This works fine, and I do have now the right component at the right place without this ugly switch-like composite. Anyway, on postbacks, I get an `IllegalStateException : Component ID [...] has already been found in the view`... Any clue ?

Comment: Which component is it? Which JSF 2.1 impl/version?

Comment: I am using Mojarra 2.1.28 and the component is the one added. The listener seems to be called twice, at restore view phase and at render response phase...

Comment: This is awkward. The listener isn't supposed to be called during render response. If I have time, I'll investigate if this is expected behavior. In the meanwhile, you could add a check on this condition. See updated answer.

Comment: Nice! Already done, and working ;-) Thank you very much for your precious help ! Regards